# What is output from OpenCV's Dense optical flow (Farneback) function? Cpp

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

First of all sorry for my bad english.

So, im using dense optical flow, GunnarFarneback speciffically. The code works fine.
Here's the code:

```
    #include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

   // Display the results of the matches
     //
   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
cv::Mat res, img1, img2, img2Original, img2OriginalC;
cv::VideoWriter writer;

 cv::VideoCapture cap;
//cv::VideoCapture cap("prueba1.mp4");
// cap.open(std::string(argv[1]));
cap.open(0);


cv::namedWindow("cat", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cap >> img1;
cvtColor(img1, img1, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
double fps = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS);
//cv::Size tamano((int)cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),      (int)cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
Size S = Size((int) cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),(int) cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
writer.open("mouse.avi", CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps, S);

for (;;) {
    cap >> img2;
    if (img2.empty()) break;

    img2.copyTo(img2OriginalC);
    cvtColor(img2, img2, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    img2.copyTo(img2Original);
    cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback(img1, img2, res, .4, 1, 12, 2, 8, 1.2, 0);
    for (int y = 0; y < img2.rows; y += 5) {
        for (int x = 0; x < img2.cols; x += 5)
        {
            // get the flow from y, x position * 3 for better visibility
            const Point2f flowatxy = res.at<Point2f>(y, x) * 1;
            // draw line at flow direction
            line(img2OriginalC, Point(x, y), Point(cvRound(x + flowatxy.x), cvRound(y + flowatxy.y)), Scalar(255, 0, 0));
            // draw initial point
            circle(img2OriginalC, Point(x, y), 1, Scalar(0, 0, 0), -1);
        }
    }
    img2Original.copyTo(img1);
    imshow("cat", img2OriginalC);
    writer << img2OriginalC;    

    cout <<"Fps"<<endl;
    cout <<fps<< endl;
    for( int i=3; i>=0; i--)
    {
        //cout<< res << endl;
        //return 0;
    }



    if (cv::waitKey(1) == 27) break;
}
cap.release();
return 0;
```

}

i think i know whats the output matrix but im not sure at all. Also,i dont know what does the values mean, finally does anyone knows how to use that output data?? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you know what optical flow means ?

Comment: I think so, its the pattern of motions between objects caused by a motion. I might put my question wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the output when we run the dense optical flow (farnnback)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924869/what-exactly-is-the-output-when-we-run-the-dense-optical-flow-farnnback)